# Limitation of input type in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I trying to create a Regular Expression for a password that can accept only
digits and letters **(a-zA-Z)**.

In the password at least one digit must to be, and at least one letter. All the text between 10-12 symbols.

I created the next `REGEX`  :

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{10,12}$/
```

The problem is that any signs like `$,%me,@,space` also acceptable.

How can I add a rule saying any others signs accepts letters,digits are not acatbale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.`, which is *any* character, use `[A-Za-z0-9]`:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{10,12}$/
```

The lookaheads will be satisfied as long as there is a single alphabetic and a single numeric character in the 10-12 list of characters, but `.` allows any of the other 8-10 characters be anything.

However, I would suggest you not do this because requirements on passwords are not a good thing.  You should let people enter whatever password they want.

Comment: ...While making sure to properly escape all input. (Had to be mentioned in case)

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

and with limit:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,12}$/
```

Comment: The requirement is to have at least one alphabetic and at least one numeric character, but your regex allows for all alphabetic or all numeric characters